# remove duplicates using visual studio regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012

I've the below text in a file.

```
abc1
x
abc1
y
abc1
z
abc2
x
abc3
x
abc3
y
```

here i want to replace the following duplicates, but remain the letter below as it is.

In simple i want the output to be as below.

```
abc1
x
y
z
abc2
x
ab3
x
y
```

please let me know how i can delete these duplicates in visual studio or any other tool using regex. i'm really unable to find a way to do it. Even a macro can be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is probably not the best solution for this problem, but with creativity it can be done:

```
(^\w{2,})(?<=^\1(\n\w)*\n\1$)
```

replace with:

```
<<empty string>>
```

Explained:

1. Find a key that contains letters and numbers and is longer than 1 character: `(^\w{2,})`
2. Look back to see if the same key is mentioned before it `(?<= ... )`
3. Find the same key as we matched before and is the only thing on the same line `^\1`
4. Skip any line with just one character `(\n\w)*`
5. Skip the key we just read `\n\1$`

Using Visual Studio Regex (in editor) is a little more complex it seems, this works:

```
(?:\r?\n)?(^\w{2,})(?:\r?\n)?(?<=^\1\r?\n(?:\w\r?\n)*\1)
```

See:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could read your text into a set(in c++ and python) then output the result key.
[cpp set reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/)

python example

```
for i in set( x for x in open( '1.txt' ).read( ).replace( '\n' ,' ' ).split( ' ' ) if x ):
    print( i )
```